# Postgres sql Insert overwrite mode

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, hive

Is there any Insert overwrite mode in postgres sql like below.

`INSERT OVERWRITE INTO TABLE table2 select * FROM table1;`

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has the TRUNCATE command to wipe the contents of a table but keep the table itself. You would have to use two statements:

```
TRUNCATE table2;
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

If you want to INSERT new records and UPDATE existing records you can use the ON CONFLICT argument of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, name) 
(SELECT id, name FROM table1)
ON CONFLICT (id_pkey) DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name;
```

You need to have a primary key or UNIQUE constraint to perform the conflict check. Full details can be viewed in the INSERT Statement documentation, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

You can also choose to DO NOTHING on conflict which has the advantage of protecting against inserting duplicate records.